# Customize Firebase Reset email content

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using `Firebase` in my app and one of the things that I added recently was the option to send a reset password link.

When the user receives the email it looks as follows:

[image]

Is there any option to read certain data from my `Firebase firestore` and display it in the email?

For example, when `user1` registered to the app he needed to set an email and a username (say: user1_cool). Now, when user1 sent himself a reset link I had like it to show:

```
Hello user1_cool, 
...
```

From this [link](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000714), it seems impossible but still was wondering if someone found a way.

Right now my email is as follows:

```
<p>Hello %DISPLAY_NAME%,</p>
<p>Follow this link to reset your password for your %EMAIL% account.</p>
<p><a href='%LINK%'>%LINK%</a></p>
<p>If you didn’t ask to reset your password, you can ignore this email.</p>
<p>Thanks,</p>
<p>NeighborBook team</p>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only change a few things about the emails that Firebase sends, as otherwise this functionality could be abused to deliver irrelevant content.

If you want full control over the emails that are sent, you'll need to implement your own email delivery. You can still use Firebase Authentication's handler for the links in that email, but following the documentation on [customizing the email handler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler).

Answer (score 2):

Well, as far as I know,

> Is there any option to read certain data from my Firebase firestore
> and display it in the email?

No, Currently there is no possibility of that in firebase ...

But since you mentioned about user setting a user name I am writing an alternative for this

If you want to show user name in `%DISPLAY_NAME%` you can modify user display name like this if you want

```
UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
        .setDisplayName("Custom User Name Goes Here")
        .build();
```

This will modify user display name and when you use the same template for the email the username set by the user will be sent instead of usual display name

> Note:  This is recommended and should be only used in this
> specific case

For more info visit : [UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder)